# Can not install Windows 10 in Virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I have a really strange problem: I downloaded a Windows10 ISO and wanted
to make a virtual Windows System on my Ubuntu Linux Box and windows does 
exactly nothing. Ok, to be fair, this happened.

[image: Ok, to be fair, this happened.]

I have let this happen for about an hour, but nothing changed, I checked if the
virtual machine is configured to use Windows x64 which it is. I did not find 
anything similar in the internet but I need the machine to test my Java programs on Windows (if all libs are working properly). Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the ISO is good? Can you download a new ISO from different source (directly from Microsoft if possible)?

Comment: I tried md5, downloaded it a second time and always from the official microsoft, so I am quite sure the iso is good. But thats what I first thought, too.

Comment: It stayed on that screen for how long? I've seen VM takes a while to boot up (due to reading the iso from a slow HDD) - I'd say... 5 minutes is safe to say it is not booting up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an update which was not in the repositories yet, but I installed it, now Windows will boot and let itself install to the harddrive. I guess this comes with some of the redstone updates, maybe they have broken something.